# AEM 6.2 | Trying to create pages under /etc hierarchy with touch ui, but touch ui sidekick doesn't shows up

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have created a new template (with sling:resourceSuperType : wcm/foundation/components/page ) and trying to create content with it in /etc hierarchy, but touch ui sidekick doesn't shows up. when i try to use the same template to create content under /content it work perfectly fine and touch ui sidekick is perfectly initialize and i am able to add touch ui component.

My hunch is it is failing, as it is trying to initialize classic UI dialog although i am trying to open page in touch ui mode and with wcm/foundation/components/page as superResourceType.

Note: Page work perfectly fine if i use the classic UI, but the issue is my component support only touch ui dialog.

Comment: Would you place some code? It would be more clear to understand your issue.

Comment: Sample page template / Page component  and page content is available @ https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uTPXRasKBhbjlKbnVhYXR6a2s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TouchUI won't work for the paths starting `/etc`, `AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl` implements a filter and explicitly enforces ClassicUI for path starting with `/etc` excluding `/etc/commerce`.